# Challenge : Create a star shaped crosswords (Smaller numbers of distinct letters wins !)

Tags: wordplay, open-ended, crosswords

[image: Star-shaped crossword]

**Rules:**

- Create a star-shaped crossword using 6 letters English words.
- Clues for the crossword is not needed.
- Use common English words.
- Direction for diagonals is TOP to DOWN.
- Direction for Horizontal is LEFT to RIGHT.

**Example:**

[image: Example]
The words used in the example are : states, latent, steaks, strait and learns
There are 9 distinct letters used "**aeiklnrst**"

**Challenge:**

This is an open ended Challenge.
Find the crossword with smaller numbers of distinct letters used.
The fastest with the smaller numbers of  distinct letters wins.

Comment: If Deus does this, he'll probably do 'A reckless disregard for star-shaped crosswords'.

Comment: Now I'll be disappointed if this *doesn't* happen.

Comment: Since when did puzzle golfing become a thing...?

Comment: I've got a set of words with just three letters, but I don't think they'll fit into a star crossword: sestet, settee, tsetse, testes, testee (maybe also setees? alternate spelling of settees).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found an example using 4 distinct letters:

> The letters used are: "eort"
>  The words used are: tooter, totter, rooter, retter and rotter
>  [image]

Seeing as RETTER isn't exactly a common word, another solution would be:

> 5 letters: "elort" with the words: tooter, totter, looter, letter and rotter
>  5 letters: "enort" with the words: tooner, totter, rooter, renter and rotter

Comment: What is the fourth word in your list?

Comment: @tmpearce RETTER: one that rets (you can check it out on: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retter )

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doesn't pass the third instruction (use common English words)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a common word but it's English, it appears in dictionaries (Merriam Webster and Oxford) and it's not denoted as "archaic" or "disused".

Comment: I like your 5 letter solutions!

Comment: To add to the 5s, "deipr": deeper, dipper, peeper, pepper, ripper (most common set of words I've found)

Comment: @practiced_liar : You win for 5 letters words

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is against the rules

> but I think you can put [terret](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/terret) everywhere. and you only use 3 letters

Let me know if this works. If not, I will delete it.

Comment: You can do the same with words like "sasses" with the benefit of it being a more common english word

Comment: @tmpearce. Do it.

Comment: REDDER would also work.

Comment: +1 Great answer, but what I mean is 5 distinct words.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to do it in 7 letters

> Letters: AEHORST
>  Words: ASSETS, ASSERT, TASERS, THESES, TOSSES
>  [image: WordStar]

Comment: Diagonals need to go from top to bottom, so one of your words is backwards

Answer (score 3):

Here's one with 7 letters

> [image]

Using:

> SPEEDS, STEEDS, SHEETS, STEELS, SLEETS - Letters are DEHLTSP